# Time management and scheduler for students

Tags: windows, time-management

Please tell me if there is any software or freeware which allows me to just enter my study topic list and time given for each topic and **it automatically generates a schedule** for me accordingly.

Actually, I surfed for softwares which provided me facilities like enter what do you want to do this day or that day and so on. But I wanted a software that handles my time by every hour and the hour schedule not should be assigned by me but automatically by the program according to the time availability.

For instance : if I added 4 topics that I have to study from physics in 2 days. I have also assigned time for 4 topics.
Let say:

1. Newtons law   - 4 hours.
2. Gravitational Force - 6 hours.
3. Motion in 3D - 2 hours.
4. Momentum - 5 hours.

Now according to given data, the program should give me a schedule for two days in which these all topics should be covered within 9 hours a day.

Normally a common program should say that you should study topic 1 then 2 then 3...

But as you can see topic 1 and 2 cover 10 hours a day. It should be like study topic 1, then 4.

Comment: Welcome on Software Recommendation. Your question looks like the beginning of a very interesting question, but SR's scope is about precise recommendations, and your requirements are quite broad. Can you add more detail about your needs? You also should read [this meta post](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) about minimum question quality requirements.

Comment: yeah, now I have edited it n also @Fractaliste helped me doing so. Now I think the question is bit clear. Please ask if I had left something. Thank You.